# Outlook calendar unable to sync description from .ics file

Tags: outlook, icalendar, outlook-calendar

I am trying to create calendar events in outlook from .ics received in mail. This is the content of the ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Demo descr
DTSTART:20220924T103000Z
DTEND:20220924T113000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=xyz@abc.com:mailto:xyz@abc.com
UID:4763547133112123311211d1121121s11e133111112112112
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=xyz@outlook.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:xyz@outlook.com
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:check description
LOCATION:somelink
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Everything is synced properly except the description part. However if i add the ics file directly in the calendar by importing, the description is reflected.

Can anyone please help me here?